# How to set location in pass dynamically

Tags: php, json, passbook

I have many locations to put in pass. Before, I just set those locations statically. Now, I create a company table and I create an interface for adding, deleting and updating the detail of company already. Thus, I should create those location of company since I create a pass. Therefore, how should I set them dynamically ? I use code like this for static locations:

```
$pass->setJSON('{...........
"locations" : [
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89529371261597,
      "latitude" : 11.576150037278605,
      "relevantText": "CamMob (dis. 1%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89823341369629,
      "latitude" : 11.570705493829758,
      "relevantText": "ITC (dis. 2%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.91380631923676,
      "latitude" : 11.553425198985883,
      "relevantText": "Digi (dis. 10%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.92096781730652,
      "latitude" : 11.569580835552655,
      "relevantText": "Central market (dis. 10%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89310503005981,
      "latitude" : 11.569444194519487,
      "relevantText": "IFL (dis. 20%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89041209220886,
      "latitude" : 11.568655879564044,
      "relevantText": "RUPP (dis. 5%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89643096923828,
      "latitude" : 11.568613836037402,
      "relevantText": "Children hospital (dis. 50%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89986419677734,
      "latitude" : 11.566343476220418,
      "relevantText": "Santhormuk high school (dis. 15%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89693522453308,
      "latitude" : 11.573774631737194,
      "relevantText": "Royal ratanak hospital (dis. 25%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89693522453308,
      "latitude" : 11.573774631737194,
      "relevantText": "AEU (dis. 30%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.8942369222641,
      "latitude" : 11.561511017118434,
      "relevantText": "Moon Car Wash (dis. 10%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.92413818836212,
      "latitude" : 11.553772076702026,
      "relevantText": "Auto Spa (dis. 10%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.9108076095581,
      "latitude" : 11.545604569281316,
      "relevantText": "Penh Chet (dis. 5%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89751189947128,
      "latitude" : 11.590985354685541,
      "relevantText": "E-garage (dis. 5%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.91095378994942,
      "latitude" : 11.562604174491218,
      "relevantText": "Futaba Garage (dis. 5%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.91638526320457,
      "latitude" : 11.55557478276799,
      "relevantText": "Haojue Motorcycle (dis. 3%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.90114092826843,
      "latitude" : 11.545636104516502,
      "relevantText": "Ice City Skating Rink (dis. 20%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.93705168366432,
      "latitude" : 11.5573354320172,
      "relevantText": "Galaxkate (dis. 10%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.92472290992737,
      "latitude" : 11.553572359281521,
      "relevantText": "G-rise photography (dis. 20%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.92827415466309,
      "latitude" : 11.556431458262171,
      "relevantText": "Portor School International Kindergarten (dis. 5%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.92472290992737,
      "latitude" : 11.553572359281521,
      "relevantText": "Cambridge International School of Cambodia (dis. 15%)"
    },
    {
      "longitude" : 104.89523202180862,
      "latitude" : 11.569042154169637,
      "relevantText": "EZECOM (dis. 35.5%)"
    }
  ]
    }');
```

Comment: Fetch the records, produce an array as wanted & encode it into a json string.

Comment: How do I use array to set them all by selecting from company table ?

Comment: "locations" : [
{ "longitude" : "'.$long.'",
      "latitude" : "'.$lat.'",
      "relevantText": "'.$name.' '.$discount.'"
   }}

Comment: so if 1 location has 4 elements , so I have to have 4 arrays ?

Comment: As I said you need to re-format the array as you want. Can you post your resultant array in question ?

Comment: Sorry, I not yet create it as I am thinking of structure of database in order to set locations to pass !

Comment: what I wrote in comment above is what I want but I don't set it yet !

Comment: Can you post your code you have tried ? And what is your real question ?

Comment: $query5 = mysql_query("select * from company");
 while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($query5)){
  $companyName = $row5['relevantTextName'];
  $discount = $row5['relevantTextDiscount'];
  $long = $row5['longitute'];
  $lat = $row5['latitute'];
  $link = $row5['link'];
  error_log("company name: ".$companyName,0);
 
      /*"longitude" : "'.$long.'",
      "latitude" : "'.$lat.'",
      "relevantText": "'.$companyName.' (dis.'.$dis.')"*/
    }

Comment: I can select all from company table, but how can I write them to location field like I did before ?

Comment: I don't how to write array for json !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just try this and I can see the result like what I wrote statically:

```
$query5 = mysql_query("select * from company");
```

`while ($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($query5)){
    $companyName = $row5['relevantTextName'];
    $discount = $row5['relevantTextDiscount'];
    $long = $row5['longitute'];
    $lat = $row5['latitute'];
    $link = $row5['link'];

    $location['locations'][] = array("longitute" => $long, "latitute" => $lat, "relevantText" => $companyName." (" . $discount. "%)" );
}
$jsonString = json_encode($location) ;

error_log("Locations: ".$jsonString,0);`

Answer (score 2):

do

```
$qry = mysql_query($conn, "select longitude, latitude, relevantText from location_table");
$ret = array();
while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $ret[] = $rec;
}
// return or print or do something with the data here.
return json_encode(array("locations"=>$ret));
```

json_encode will return numericaly indexed php arrays as json arrays and arrays with string indexes as javascript objects... hope this helps

Comment: Also remember that a pass can only have 10 locations.  The rest would be ignored so you should add `LIMIT 10` to the query, and should probably also add a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` condition to provide some logic of which 10 will be selected.

Comment: looking at the json you are trying to reproduct the last line should actually read return json_encode(array("locations"=>$ret));

Comment: Why I can only use 10 locations ?

Comment: gHow many time have I sent you a link to the documentation!!! Read it, it will tell you there is a limit. You even posted a question asking why you were seeing an error because of too many locations! Apple have decided that the limit is 10. Just imagine how big a pass would be if it had every single Starbucks or McDonnalds location in it. These files have to be downloaded over cellular networks - if they are too large, the user experience will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
<?php
$locations = array();
$result = $mysqli->query("select longitude, latitude, relevantText FROM company");

$inc=0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $locations['locations'][$inc]['longitude'] = $row['longitude'];
        $locations['locations'][$inc]['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
        $locations['locations'][$inc]['relevantText'] = $row['relevantText'];

    $inc++;
    }

echo json_encode($locations);

?>
```